# Issue persisting data in spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm starting to make a project in spring mvc, and i'm having some doubts when getting types from jsp to the controller.

At the moment i have (jsp):

```
<form method="POST" action="pb.html">           
<h2>Description: <textarea style="resize:none;" name="description" form="usrform" maxlength="47"></textarea><h2> 
<br>          
Number: <input type="number" min="1" value="1" name="number" />
<input type="submit" value="Create Volume" />
</form>
```

My controller:

```
package book;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class BookController {

@Autowired
private BookDao bookDAO;

@RequestMapping(value="/book")
public ModelAndView BOOKSTORE(HttpServletRequest request) {
String description = request.getParameter("description");
String number = request.getParameter("number");

if(description != null && number != null)    
bookDAO.persist(new Book(description, Integer.parseInt(number)));

// Prepare the result view (book.jsp):
return new ModelAndView("book.jsp", "bookDao", bookDAO);
}
}
```

It seems that my data is not being persisted because the contoller cannot transform the textarea into a string, and for some reason it cannot transform the number.

Some sites say to use in jsp the following:

```
<h2>Description: <input type="text" name="description"></input><h2> 
<br>          
Number: <input type="text" name="number" />
```

But this doesn't make sense to me, because i want the user to view the full description (so i need a text area) and i only want the user to type numbers on the number field, so it makes more sense to use the tye number.

Can anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: Add the stored book not the Dao to the model and use the spring form tags to bind the result.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/book")
public ModelAndView BOOKSTORE(HttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView  mav) {
String description = request.getParameter("description");
String number = request.getParameter("number");

Book book=new Book();
if(description != null && number != null){
     book=new Book(description, Integer.parseInt(number));
     bookDAO.persist(book);
}

mav.setViewName("book");
mav.addObject("book", book);
return mav;
}
}
```

Comment: With this code i get an error: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException: bean bookDao not found within scope

Comment: I also had to change mav.setViewName("book"); to mav.setViewName("book.jsp"); , otherwise i would get an Error 404

Comment: If i change mav.addObject("book", book); to mav.addObject("bookDao", bookDAO); the program doesn't give me an error, but also doesn't persist and show anything when i click submit.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

I had to pass the number as a string to the java class and inside the java class i did the null validation:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/book")
public ModelAndView BOOKSTORE(HttpServletRequest request) {
String description = request.getParameter("description");
String number = request.getParameter("number");

if(description != null)    
bookDAO.persist(new Book(description, number));

// Prepare the result view (book.jsp):
return new ModelAndView("book.jsp", "bookDao", bookDAO);
}
```

Java:

```
/**
 *
 * @param description
 * @param number
 */
public Book(String description, String number){
    this.pbi_description = description;

    if(number!= null)
        this.number=  Integer.parseInt(number);  
}
```

However, it should be possible to do this validation in the controller.

Comment: resolved the problem, there was a problem in my jsp, i had put the number as a list.